# How to put "#nullable" after using (import) block after code reformat

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, rider, nullable-reference-types

How to say to Rider (Resharper) put `#nullable` after using (import) block after code reformat?

My example:

- Preconditions:

  - `JetBrains Rider 2022.1.2`. I expect the same results with `Resharper` because `Rider` and `Resharper` use the same settings.
  - File with content:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable enable

internal record Response
{
    public IList<decimal>? Items { get; init; }
}
```

- Steps:

  1. Choose the file in solution explorer
  2. Context menu -> Refactor this -> Move to folder

Actual result:

- `#nullable enable` was moved before using (import) block.

```cs
#nullable enable

using System.Collections.Generic;

internal record Response
{
    public IList<decimal>? Items { get; init; }
}
```

Expected result:

- File content did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with both Rider and R# and was not able to produce your desired behavior. So I assume that's not yet supported

Maybe you can create a ticket at JetBrains so that they can track it as a feature request.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. As I understand this is not implemented in rider. So, there is the ticket for it https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-489353 and
[Rider Support Community Post](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/6777729826578-How-to-put-nullable-after-using-import-block-after-code-reformat)

Comment: Thanks for keeping us updated! Maybe you can mark it as an answer so that the question gets closed?